# Formula to calculate heating time of nichrome?

Tags: heat, thermal, heater

Is there a formula to calculate how long it will take for a nichrome (NiCr-A) rod of given dimensions to heat up to a certain temperature (or maximum temperature) for a given supply of AC or DC current and voltage to the rod.
Assume the rod is surrounded by stationary air at ambient temperature (~25°C).

Comment: There will be but it won't be very accurate so, if you need great accuracy you could use a FEA tool that modeled it.

Comment: @DKNguyen No. The answers to that question doesn't discuss heating time.

Comment: But it does. Think about it. Heating time is a transient response which is more advanced than a steady state equilibrium temperature. So if the simpler case is already complicated enough to not have an equation and need software, then what do you think the more advanced case will be like?

Comment: You need to determine how much heat will be lost through the connections to the rod (by conduction) and also how much is lost by radiation. But, as has been said, if you ignore convection the results will be pretty poor.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there’s a formula, and I’ll leave this to the end.

The question you’re asking isn’t just about the formula. It’s about the parameters that go into it.

The parameters you need to figure out include:

- *thermal resistance*, specified in degrees rise / W.
- *wire resistance*, specified in ohms / unit length
- *specific heat capacity*, specified in energy /(mass*temperature)

*Thermal resistance* for the nichrome rod (thick wire) will have two components:
 - from the wire to ambient, θ<sub>(ja)</sub>
 - from the wire to its holder, θ<sub>(jb)</sub>

Both θ<sub>(ja)</sub> and θ<sub>(jb)</sub> are in units of deg. C/W.

You will also need to know the thermal rise per unit length of your wire given a current input, which you can get from the manufacturer. A hint: if you also know the mass per unit length, you can get an idea of specific heat capacity as well.

Here’s a table of thermal rise vs. current for various sizes of nichrome wire: http://hotwirefoamcutterinfo.com/_NiChromeData_files/1_Amperage.jpg

Armed with all this, if you have access to a thermal modeling tool you can build a model that will predict the rise per W of power, and the rate-of-rise, for all parts of the structure.

But to predict this accurately, you need to know *all* the thermal resistance characteristics of all the pieces that come into contact with the heated rod, which includes the holder, what that holder is connected to, the contacts with the rod, and the wiring carrying the current. All these will conduct heat away from the rod and thus lower its temperature.

In other words, your model is only as good as the data you supply it.

If you're like most of us, you don’t have that expensive software tool, the experience to use it, or know all those parameters to construct an accurate thermal model.

What to do then? You will have to use measurements of the actual wire/rod and its holding apparatus to determine the overall θ<sub>(ja)</sub> and θ<sub>(jb)</sub>, and measure the net rate-of-rise. And if airflow is involved you will need to characterize those values vs. airflow velocity as well.

This isn’t nearly as bad as it sounds. It’s fairly standard work for product validation. It does take time and an investment in thermal measurement equipment. In your case you could probably make do with a bench supply and a thermal imaging camera, which would give good insight into where the heat is flowing when you pass current through the nichrome rod. It will also illustrate how you should design the holder, contacts and wiring to minimize heat transfer.

---

And now, the math.

Having done that groundwork, you will have in-hand the values needed to predict temperature vs. power input as follows:

- degrees rise, in deg. C = W * (θ<sub>(ja)</sub>*θ<sub>(jb)</sub>) / (θ<sub>(ja)</sub>+θ<sub>(jb)</sub>)

This gives the steady-state temperature at a given power input for your system in free air.

As for *how long it takes to reach that state*, that is dependent on the mass of all the pieces and the environment, and their specific heat capacities.

The formula to calculate the heat rise of a material is:

- *Q* = *mc∆T*

Where *m* is material mass, *c* is heat capacity (in Joules/(kg*deg K), *Q* is energy input in joules, and *∆T* is of course change in temperature.

Time for a given Q is then:

- *t = Q / W*

Putting it all together, solve for *t*, carry the 1...

- *t = mc∆T / W*

More here: https://sciencing.com/calculate-time-heat-object-8223103.html

Note that this calculation is for an ideal system with infinite thermal resistance. In a real system, the heat will be bleeding off into the air and everything that's touching the heated element.

An exercise left for the student: build a lossy thermal model expressing the thermal mass of the components as capacitance, and thermal resistance as... resistance.

Here's an example thermal model done in Mathworks: https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/simscape/examples/heat-conduction-through-iron-rod.html

Comment: SE supports HTML entities and superscript and subscript. Try `&theta;<sub>ja</sub>`.

Comment: First draft. I’ll shine it up in a bit.

Answer (score 2):

here is a hint

Silicon (not nichrome) has thermal capacity of 1.6 picoJoules per cubic micron per degree Centigrade. When you short the output of a modern MCU, or logic gate such as 74HCT00, you will very rapidly heat the internal FETs, perhaps to destruction. The numerous thermal paths are not able to remove the heat fast enough, and the tiny transistors self-destruct.

If your energy input to your nichrome is very high, then the AIR and the MOUNTING CLAMPS will not matter.

In that case, all you care about is the volume of the "wire", its total specific heat, and the rate of energy input.

Answer (score 2):

As a first approximation I would calculate the temperature rise from

$$ \Delta T = \frac {P \times t}{m \times SHC} $$

where

- ΔT = temperature rise in K (°C).
- P = power (W).
- t = time (s).
- m = mass (kg).
- SHC = specific heat capacity (Jkg<sup>−1</sup>°C<sup>−1</sup>).

SHC for Nichrome is 450 Jkg<sup>−1</sup>°C<sup>−1</sup>.

This ignores all heat lost through convection, radiation and conductivity.

You can calculate the power from \$ P = \frac {V^2} R = I^2R \$ but bear in mind that R will change with temperature.